# laravel - uploading multiple files but stores one

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload multiple images and store their paths in a JSON format with IDs to every path. This is my controller code:

```
if(is_dir($request->file('imgs')))
        {
            $data['imgs'] = $this->ProductRepository->uploadMultiImages($request->file('imgs'));
        } elseif (is_file($request->file('imgs')))
        {
            $data['imgs'] = Utilities::upload($request->file('imgs'), 'products');
        }
```

this is the `ProductRepository->uploadMultiImages` code:

```php
public function uploadMultiImages(UploadedFile $images)
    {
        $countOfImages = 0;
        $storedImages = collect();
        foreach ($images as $image)
        {
            $storedImages->push([
                'id' => $countOfImages++,
                'path' => ($path = Utilities::upload($image, 'products')),
            ]);
        }
        return $storedImages;
    }
```

and here's my `Utilities::upload` function code:

```php
public static function upload(UploadedFile $file, $filePath)
    {
        return (string)$file->store($filePath, 'public');
    }
```

What I'm getting stored in the database is only one image, using postman.
So, any ideas of solving this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put [] in postman to accept it all, also adding this in validation :

```
'file'=>'file',
'file.*'=>'type|of|files|im|accepting'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is storing only one image because it never enters the `if` statement.

`$request->file()` will always be an uploaded file so always enter `Utilities::upload` function. And in that function you are not iterating the images one by one but you are directly saving a single file.

My suggestion to solve the problem is that you edit your `Utilities::upload` method and place something like this.

```
public function upload(array $photos)
{
    $photos = collect($photos)->map(function ($photo){
        return $photo->store('photos');
    });

    return $photos;
}
```

Comment: What do you suggest me to do in this case if I need to store the paths of all files I'm getting ? and should I use allFiles() method ?